# Displaying number of children in collapse tree

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using mbostock's [Collapse tree](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083).

[image]

I need to display number of children along with node name in each node such as "flare (10)", "analytics (3)".

I tried using...

```
  nodeEnter.append("text")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
  .text(function(d) { return d.name + " (" + d.children.length() + ")"; })
  .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
```

but that doesn't seem to work. How can I get children count of a node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, but there are two issues with your code.

1. The length is a *property* of an array in Javascript, so you access it without parentheses:

   ```
   >>> L = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
   >>> L.length
   3
   ```
2. You need to take into account the fact that some nodes `d` have `d.children`, some nodes have `d._children`, and some have no children at all. Try something like this:

   ```
   .text(function(d) {
       var numChildren = 0;
       if (d.children) numChildren = d.children.length;
       else if (d._children) numChildren = d._children.length;
       return d.name + " (" + numChildren + ")";
   })
   ```

And here's what you get:

[image]